# Knockout js bindingHandlers extension not updating text input control on some character input

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to create an knockout extension for phone number formatting.
First time when I enter 2139139090 to 213-913-9090, the phone number is formatted correctly. Immediately after, if I remove the hyphen(-) from the number, it is not formatted in the text control. But if I log the formatted value to console from js code, it shows as formatted. Same behavior for space, +1 like special characters. If I change any digit in the number all formatting works fine.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="userform-phone" data-bind="textInputPhone:user.phone" /> 



ko.bindingHandlers.textInputPhone = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                $(element).on('blur', function () {
                    var inputvalue = $(element).val().trim();
                    var observable = valueAccessor();
                    if (inputvalue) {
                        var regexstring = /^(?:\+?1)?\(?[- .]?(\d{3})\)?[- .]?(\d{3})[- .]?(\d{4})([-. ]?[a-zA-z].*)?$/gm
                        var phoneformat = '$1-$2-$3$4';
                        var formattedPhoneNumber = inputvalue.replace(regexstring, phoneformat);
                        observable(formattedPhoneNumber);
                    } else {
                        observable('');
                    }
                });
            },
            update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                $(element).val(valueUnwrapped);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a `ko.observable`, it checks if the new value is different from the value it already holds. If the values are the same, **it doesn't notify any of its subscribers.**

When you enter your first number, you set the observable to `"213-913-9090"`. Any time the `<input>` blurs, you reevaluate the value. Now here's the catch:

If you only alter white space, the outcomes *before* and *after* the edit will be exactly the same. This means your `update` is not triggered, and the `.val(valueUnwrapped)` is never called.

Two quick fixes you could make:

- call `observable.notifySubscribers` after you've set the observable with the same value, or
- extend `user.phone` using `.extend({ notify: 'always' })`

Alternatively, you could try a different approach using a custom extender like in [this example (Example 1)](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html).

A quickly fixed example:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.textInputPhone = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    $(element).on('blur', function() {
      var inputvalue = $(element).val().trim();
      var observable = valueAccessor();
      var newValue = '';

      if (inputvalue) {
        var regexstring = /^(?:\+?1)?\(?[- .]?(\d{3})\)?[- .]?(\d{3})[- .]?(\d{4})([-. ]?[a-zA-z].*)?$/gm
        var phoneformat = '$1-$2-$3$4';
        var formattedPhoneNumber = inputvalue.replace(regexstring, phoneformat);
        newValue = formattedPhoneNumber;
      }

      // Option 1: notify explicitly
      if (observable.peek() === newValue) {
        observable.notifySubscribers(newValue);
      } else {
        observable(newValue);
      }
    });
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    $(element).val(valueUnwrapped);
  }
}

ko.applyBindings({
  user: {
    phone: ko.observable("") //.extend({notify: 'always'}) // Option 2
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input data-bind="textInputPhone:user.phone" />
```

Comment: Works Great. Thank you.